# Numerical method for finding a parameter inside an integral

Tags: numerical-methods, regression

I have a set of data, basically with the information of f(x) as a function of x, and x itself. I know from the theory of the problem that I'm working on the format of f(x), which is given as the expression below:

[image: equation 1]

Essentially, I want to use this set of data to find the parameters a and b but I don't know any numetical methods that could be used to this task since the x itself is in one of the limits of integration.

Could any one help me with that? Can be anything a name of a method, a clue. Literally anything.

I would also like to point out that [I posted this question in stack overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59724077/fitting-parameter-with-python-inside-an-integral) looking for a pratical answer and in case of need, in this page there is some links with the data set that I'm working on. However, besides any answer I can get from stack overflow I would like to know the numerical methods that I could use to solve this problem.

Thanks in advance guys!

**EDIT 1:** Well guys, turns out I was trying to solve my problem in pieces. The problem in all its glory is actually given by the following integral:

[image: equation_2]

I'm gratefull for the answer given below for the first case! I did learn with that. But I could not generalize it for the integral above. I actually think that this one can not be solved analitically. So I think that my biggest question remains:

Could any one help me with a way for finding the parameters inside the integral? Can be anything a name of a method, a clue. Literally anything. 
And for what matters all the parameters are supposed to be bigger than zero, and b, c and d can be correlated.

**EDIT 2:** I also know that there is a relationship among b, c and d of the following kind: b+c+d = constant, and MAYBE, MAYBE this constant is equal to one.

Also, I would like a way to first find two parameters: a and one inside the integral. Actually, to me it doesn't matter which one, I would be happy in any case. But if I could, I would say that preferably I would like to find d. And in case of this approach not be possible, I would like to have a method to:

- Find the parameter a alone, supposing that I do know b, c, and d.
- Find one of the parameters inside the integral, preferably d.

Comment: I posted my answer which gives a very simple method on stackoverflow : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59724077/fitting-parameter-inside-an-integral-using-python-or-another-useful-language

Comment: Your question is still not well-posed. The equation in "Edit 1" includes four parameters $a,b,c,d$ wich are not independent. One of them must be given (known). If not they are an infinity of solutions with an unknow coefficient of proportionality. Which one among $a,b,c,d$ is given ? Eventually what is his value ?

Comment: @JJacquelin I did another update in the question. Like I said, in the worst case you could suppose that I would know all the parameters inside the square root, and in the best case I would know two, like b and c, for example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Changing a little your notations, you have
$$f(x)=\int_0^x \frac{dt}{a \sqrt{b (t+1)^3+c (t+1)^4}}$$ The antiderivative does not make any problem and we have
$$f(x)=-\frac{2 \sqrt{(x+1)^3 (b+c(x+1))}}{a b (x+1)^2}+\frac{2 \sqrt{b+c}}{a b}$$ which could simplify if $(x+1)>0$. Assuming that this is the case
$$f(x)=-\frac{2 \sqrt{(x+1) (b+c(x+1))}}{a b (x+1)}+\frac{2 \sqrt{b+c}}{a b}$$

Now, I suppose that you have $n$ data points $(x_i,f(x_i))$ and you want to identify the parameters to get the best match. This is nonlinear regression.

To make the model better conditioned, I should define $d=ab$ to make
$$f(x)=-\frac{2 \sqrt{(x+1) (b+c(x+1))}}{d (x+1)}+\frac{2 \sqrt{b+c}}{d}$$

As usual, the problem is to find "reasonable" starting guesses for $(b,c,d)$ before starting the nonlinear regression.

Assuming that you have data close to $x=0$, you could use the fact that
$$f'(0)=\frac{b}{d \sqrt{b+c}}$$ which will give you an expression of an estimate of $d$ as a function of $b$ and $c$.

Similarly, assuming that you have data for large $x$, the horizontal asymptote is given by
$$f(\infty)=\frac{2 \left(\sqrt{b+c}-\sqrt{c}\right)}{d}$$ which now gives an estimate of $b$. To summarize, our estimates would be
$$b=c\frac{4f'(0) (f(\infty)-f'(0))}{(f(\infty)-2 f'(0))^2}\qquad \text{and} \qquad d=\sqrt{c}\frac{4  (f'(0)-f(\infty))}{f(\infty) (f(\infty)-2 f'(0))}$$ So, we have now $b(c)$ and $a(c)$.

Now, consider
$$SSQ(c)=\sum_{i=1}^n \left(f(x_i)-\frac{2 \sqrt{(x_i+1) (b(c)+c(x_i+1))}}{d(c) (x_i+1)}+\frac{2 \sqrt{b(c)+c}}{d(c)} \right)^2$$

Try a few values of $c$ until you see more of less a minimum of $SSQ(c)$. For this $c$, recompute $b$ and $d$ according to the approximative formulae and, at this point, you have all elements to start a nonlinear regression.

Comment: Thanks for your feed back @Claude! I was not thinking in that way. But as I explained above, I was trying to solve my problem in pieces, but I could not generalize your solution. (And turns out that solving in pieces was not a good strategy after all). Do you have any clues for the bigger problem?

Answer (score 1):

Concerning the new integral
$$I=\int \frac{dt}{a \sqrt{b (t+1)^3+c (t+1)^4+d}}$$ it is possible to compute it analytically.
Write
$$b (t+1)^3+c (t+1)^4+d=c t^4+ (b+4 c)t^3+ (3 b+6 c)t^2+ (3 b+4 c)t+(b+c+d)$$ that is to say
$$b (t+1)^3+c (t+1)^4+d=c \prod_{i=1}^4 (t-r_i)$$ where the $r_i$'s are related to $(b,c,d)$ using Vieta's formulae. So, we face
$$I=\frac 1{a \sqrt c} \int \frac{dt}{\sqrt{(t-r_1) (t-r_2) (t-r_3) (t-r_4)}}$$

Have a look [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+1%2FSqrt%5B%28t+-+r%5B1%5D%29*%28t+-+r%5B2%5D%29*%28t+-+r%5B3%5D%29*%28t+-+r%5B4%5D%29%5D+for+%24t%24) for the result (at the bottom of the page).

Since, more than likely, the $r_i$' will be complex, it could be better to write
$$b (t+1)^3+c (t+1)^4+d=c(t^2+At+B)(t^2+Ct+D)$$ to face
$$I=\frac 1{a \sqrt c} \int \frac{dt}{\sqrt{(t^2+At+B)(t^2+Ct+D)}}$$ where $(A,B,C,D)$ will be real.

Have a look [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+1%2FSqrt%5B%28B+%2B+A*t+%2B+t%5E2%29*%28D+%2B+C*t+%2B+t%5E2%29%5D+for+t) for the result.

Now, I suppose that it would be good to think about an optimization problem with a few equality constraints.

Comment: Wow @Claude Leibovici. Thanks again! Well, I think I'll need a couple of hours now thinking about your approach and how to do an optimization with that. I'll come back here in case of need.